# Random number based off of variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a random number generated based of a variable called "offset". This variable starts at 1 and can go up to 5,000,000 and counts up at a fast rate. This function would have to read offset generate a number that is higher than offset by 3000. Can figure out how to do this so asking for help.

Comment: If it's higher than offset by precisely 3000, it's not random. Did you mean "by _at least_ 3000"?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you want.  A random number can easily be generated between any two values.  What would your high and low bounds be for the random number?

Comment: Generate any random number, add (offset + 3000) to it. Done.

Comment: @paislee by at least just to give time for it to load into the frame.

Comment: Downvoting the question as it's been a little while since people asked for clarification and the question has not been clarified.  Come on people.  Either ask clear questions or monitor what people are asking about your question so you can fix what isn't clear.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have replyed to paislee about his question

Comment: Sorry, Kenp, but your response to @paislee does not clarify your question.  You haven't answered my earlier question so people are left to guess what you might mean.  Random numbers have a lower and an upper bounds (they must be between two numbers).  You haven't told us what the lower and upper bounds are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
var offset = 1;

function random() {
    offset += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + (offset + 3000);

    return offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRndNum(offset)
{
    var randomnumber=Math.floor((Math.random()*offset)+3000);
    return randomnumber;
}
```

call it like

```
getRndNum(1) // with offset number 1
getRndNum(8) // with offset number 1
```

now it's up to you to get the offset variable updated, you didn't tell anything about it.

Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mz54B/).